# Make five left floating elements with 25% width continue floating offscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have five `<li>` elements. Each `<li>` is defined with 25% width:

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

and is defined within a wrapper container:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 125%;
}
```

**What im looking to do is:** Make the four first elements appear onscreen taking up 100% width and have the last element float left offscreen.

Note: there can eventually be more than five elements.

What I experience is that although my wrapper is set to fit 5x25% = 125%, the last element "breaks" down and the fourth doesn't show fully 25% onscreen.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pJNAV/1/

Comment: Do you have any margins/paddings/border defined for your `li` elements?

Comment: Set the width of the `<li>`s to `20%`, they will still take up `125%` of the width,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have:

```
#wrapper {
width: 125%;
}
```

You have 5 elements, so each one will be a 20% of the parent element, so

```
ul li {        
    width: 20%;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJNAV/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

this means the wrapper will take up 125% of the screen, but the elements will get 20% each of that (correct mathematically). Seems to work on the jsFiddle.